# Craft 2: Exception: CException: Alias "ext.alpha" is invalid

Tags: craft-pro, manual-updates

Today I updated my craft to latest version Craft V 2.6.3015 by following [this url](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/updating.html).

I got it updated successfully and now my Craft version is 2.6.3015 which is latest of Craft 2.

After updating the Craft setup, I tested the site, and one of the page is giving an exception as mentioned below:

> Exception thrown in Make a Payment. Exception: CException: Alias "ext.alpha" is >invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable. in C:\path\craft\app\framework\YiiBase.php:324

Please help me to get rid of the error.  I checked that the Craft is not having any extension named alpha.

```
Stack trace:

#0 C:\path\craft\app\framework\validators\CValidator.php(174): YiiBase::import('ext.alpha', true)
#1 C:\path\craft\app\framework\base\CModel.php(287): CValidator::createValidator('ext.alpha', Object(Craft\BarclaycardEpdq_PaymentModel), Array, Array)
>#2 C:\path\craft\app\framework\base\CModel.php(260): CModel->createValidators()
>#3 C:\path\craft\app\framework\base\CModel.php(158): CModel->getValidators()
>#4 C:\path\craft\app\models\BaseModel.php(501): CModel->validate(NULL, true)
>#5 C:\path\craft\plugins\barclaycardepdq\services\BarclaycardEpdq_ApiService.php(213): Craft\BaseModel->validate()
>#6 C:\path\craft\plugins\barclaycardepdq\services\BarclaycardEpdq_ApiService.php(64): Craft\BarclaycardEpdq_ApiService->callBarclaycard('Craft\\Barclayca...', Array, 'https://site...', 'payByAlias')
>#7 C:\path\craft\plugins\rhp\controllers\Rhp_PaymentsController.php(129): Craft\BarclaycardEpdq_ApiService->makePaymentByAlias(Array)
>#8 C:\path\craft\app\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\Rhp_PaymentsController->actionMakeAPayment()
>#9 C:\path\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
>#10 C:\path\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
>#11 C:\path\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
>#12 C:\path\craft\app\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('makeAPayment')
>#13 C:\path\craft\app\etc\web\WebApp.php(836): CWebApplication->runController('rhp/payments/ma...')
>#14 C:\path\craft\app\etc\web\WebApp.php(287): Craft\WebApp->_processActionRequest()
>#15 C:\path\craft\app\framework\base\CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
>#16 C:\path\craft\app\index.php(73): CApplication->run()
>#17 C:\path\index.php(13): require_once('C:\\path\\...')
>#18 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download below extension and put alpha.php file in your craft extension folder:
https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/alpha

Best of luck..!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It fixed the issue. I am posting a full answer that will help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried to find a solution for the above-mentioned issue with Google and also connected to Craft community on Slack but could not find any help.

The answer from @Ankit Sompura fixed my issue.

**Step -1 :** following [the link](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/alpha) and locate **Downloads** on right hand side, and click on the link `alpha-1.0.tgz` which will get that tgz file.

**Step- 2:** After extracting the file you will get `alpha.php`.

**Step- 3:** And place the `alpha.php` file into `Craft/app/extensions/` and you are done.
Check the page again and the error will be fixed.